# How to remove "Will be installed to run from network" installation options from MSI when using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Bear with me, I'm just trying to learn [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/). I'm curious how to remove the following network installation options from this popup menu (circled in red)?

[image]

**EDIT:** As requested below, here's the `Feature` node:

```
<Feature Id='Complete' Title='Product title' Description='The complete package.'
  Display='expand' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Absent='disallow' AllowAdvertise='no' >

  <Feature Id='MainProgram' Title='Program files'
           Description='Installs the main executable files for the software.'
           Absent='disallow'
           AllowAdvertise='no'
           Level='1'>
    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDFile1EXE' />
    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDFile2EXE' />
    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDFile3EXE' />
    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDFile1DLL' />
    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDFile2DLL' />

    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDMainRegistry' />
    <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id='ShortcutsStart' Title='Start Menu Shortcuts'
           AllowAdvertise='no'
           Description="Places software shortcuts into the Windows Start Menu."
           Level='1'>
    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDShortcutsStart' />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id='ShortcutsDesktop' Title='Desktop Shortcut'
           AllowAdvertise='no'
           Description="Places software shortcut onto the users' desktops."
           Level='1000'>
    <ComponentRef Id='CompIDShortcutsDesktop' />
  </Feature>

</Feature>
```

Comment: Adding this old classic form MVP Stefan Kruger: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200102/CustomSetupOptions.htm - I presume you used an uncompressed setup image?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul: You realize that I asked this more than 3 years ago....

Comment: Yes, I saw the post changed yesterday and I wanted people to find that link if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should show your WiX source being used for the Feature elements. It's most likely a combination of the InstallDefault setting (which you probably want to be "local") and AllowAdvertise (and set it to "no").

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer. Is there something that I need to adjust there?

Comment: I can't see InstallDefault there.

Comment: I set `InstallDefault="local"` for the `<Feature Id='Complete'>` and it did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For features that do not directly contain `ComponentRef` or `ComponentGroupRef`, you just create a dummy component inside that feature with a `Location="local"` attribute. This will get rid of the "run from network" options.
Example:

```
<Feature Id='Complete' Title='Product title' Description='The complete package.'  Display='expand' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Absent='disallow' AllowAdvertise='no' >
   <!-- Dummy component to get rid of the "run from network" option  -->
   <Component Id="CompleteDummyComponent" Location="local" Directory="TARGETDIR" Guid="GUID_HERE_PLEASE" />

<!-- sub features here -->
</Feature>
```